# Communication issue between functions into JS and JSX files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, cc-2019

I have made this **function** into a **JS** file...

```
function getColors(isPick, isForecolor)
{
    var chosenFunction = 'getColor(' + isPick + ', ' + isForecolor + ')';
    csInterface.evalScript(chosenFunction, function(result)
    {
        if(result !== 'undefined')
        {
            if (isForecolor == true){
                foregroundHexColor = result;
                // etc...
            }
            else
            {
                backgroundHexColor = result;
                //etc..
            };
        };
    });
};
```

which **get** a **hexadecimal** color **value** from this **function** from a **JSX** file.

```
function getColor(isPick, isForecolor)
{
    var color_PickerCase;
    var decimal_Color;
    var hexadecimal_Color;

    if (isForecolor == true)
    {
        color_PickerCase = app.foregroundColor.rgb.hexValue;
    }
    else
    {
        color_PickerCase = app.backgroundColor.rgb.hexValue;
    };

    if (isPick == true)
    {
        if (app.showColorPicker(isForecolor)){
            decimal_Color = color_PickerCase;
            hexadecimal_Color = decimal_Color.toString(16);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        };
    }
    else
    {
        decimal_Color = color_PickerCase;
        hexadecimal_Color = decimal_Color.toString(16);
    };

    return hexadecimal_Color;    
};
```

In some way it works, but for some reason I have to do the same thing **two times** so to get the value!!! Any idea why is this happening?

Thank you for your time!!!

**UPDATE**: A correction, it works only at first click. Then needs to clicked two times so to get the value!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the color before picking. Thus you get the color form the last time you picked ;)

Anyway your code can be made better

```
function getColor(isPick, isForecolor)
{
    var color_PickerCase;
    var decimal_Color;
    var hexadecimal_Color;


    // note according to docs showColorPicker 
    // does not accept any parameters
    if (isPick === true && app.showColorPicker() === false)
    {
            return; // maybe throw an error? 
    }

    if (isForecolor === true)
    {
        color_PickerCase = app.foregroundColor.rgb.hexValue;
    }
    else
    {
        color_PickerCase = app.backgroundColor.rgb.hexValue;
    }

    decimal_Color = color_PickerCase;
    hexadecimal_Color = decimal_Color.toString(16);
    return hexadecimal_Color;    
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, it worked!!! I just had to add the `isForecolor` variable into `app.showColorPicker()` like this `app.showColorPicker(isForecolor)`, so to understands if color picker will open for foreground or background color!!! Change it at your answer if you like so to be totally correct!!! Thank you again!!! :)

Comment: You wrote that according to docs, `showColorPicker` does not accept any parameters... Please take a look [here](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/Photoshop/Application/showColorPicker.html).

Comment: @SimonetosTheGreek i know but adobes official documentation does not mention it. The danger is that they may remove undocumented functionality.